# subset from a list of data.frames in R

Tags: r, function, subset

In my function below `...` represents any vectors (e.g., `numeric` or `character` etc.) **named** by the user. For example, a user might define `age = 1:3` and `prof = c("med", "low", "med")`. These extra vectors are added to a `data.frame` called `out`.

I was wondering if there is a way I could create a new argument called `extract` to allow user to subset from the final output `h`.

For example, if a user wants to subset `age == 2` or `age == 2 & prof == "low"` the corresponding match from the output is returned by use of `extract = age == 2 & prof == "low"`?

```
foo <- function(d, per, ...){ ## Add a new argument called `extract`

 out <- data.frame(d, ...)

h <- split(out, rep(seq_along(per), per))  ## `extract` should subset from `h`
return(h)
}
# Example of use:
foo(d = 2:4, per = 1:2, age = 1:3, prof = c("med", "low", "med"))
```

Comment: Do you need `foo(d = 2:4, per = 1:2, extract =quote(age == 2), age = 1:3, prof = c("med", "low", "med"))` and inside the function `out1 <- subset(out, subset = eval(extract))`

Comment: Can you check the ssolution below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can pass the quoted expression in 'extract' and `eval`uate to filter the rows

```
library(tidyverse)
foo <- function(d, per, extract, ...){ ## Add a new argument called `extract`

   extract <- rlang::enexpr(extract)
   out <- data.frame(d, ...)


  h <- split(out, rep(seq_along(per), per))  
  map(h, ~ .x %>% 
            filter(!! extract))

 }

foo(d = 2:4, per = 1:2, extract = age == 2, age = 1:3, prof = c("med", "low", "med"))
#$`1`
#[1] d    age  prof
#<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

#$`2`
#  d age prof
#1 3   2  low
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
foo <- function(d, per, extract, ...){ ## Add a new argument called `extract`

   extract <- substitute(extract)
   out <- data.frame(d, ...)


   h <- split(out, rep(seq_along(per), per))  
   lapply(h, function(x) subset(x, subset = eval(extract)))

}

foo(d = 2:4, per = 1:2, extract = age == 2, age = 1:3, prof = c("med", "low", "med"))
```

Comment: @rnorouzian   Can the user pass it as a string `"age ==2"`

Answer (score 3):

This does not use any packages nor does it explicitly use `eval`.

```
foo2 <- function(d, per, ..., extract = TRUE) {
  out <- data.frame(...)
  h <- split(out, rep(seq_along(per), per))
  s <- substitute(extract)
  lapply(h, function(x) do.call("subset", list(x, s)))
}


foo2(d = 2:4, per = 1:2, age = 1:3, prof = c("med", "low", "med"), extract = age == 2)
```